# How to fix circular wait progress while logging out in flutter app using Firebase authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have a LoginPage() for login and a DashBoard() page which comes after logging in succesfully.
I am using a Controller() page to provide the authetication which listens for any authentication changes in firebase, it looks like this :

```
class Controller extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        else if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return DashBoard();
        }
        return LoginPage();
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

I also have a Log out button in another page. When I try to logout, it throws me first to DashBoard() page (which means that snapshot.hasData has some value) and after 2-3 seconds it throws me then to LoginPage() but the code never goes into this section

```
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
     return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

It first goes into this block conditon

```
else if (snapshot.hasData) {
     return DashBoard();
}
```

And then the LoginPage() section. Also when I try to Login, it never shows me the Circularwait, but throws me to DashBoard() page.
What is the best way to achieve this ?
My fireBase auth file looks like this :

```
class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  final googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user;

  Future signInWithGoogle() async {
    try {
      final GoogleSignInAccount googleuser = await googleSignIn.signIn();
      if (googleuser == null) return;
      _user = googleuser;

      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleuser.authentication;

      final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: googleAuth.idToken, accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken);
      // Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Account created");

      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      print(_user);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future signOutGoogle() async {
    await googleSignIn.disconnect();
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

Comment: Use bloc class and streams for logging it.  The streams will notify the streambuilder when authentication failed or succeeded

Comment: Can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: let me post a bloc authentication code example below

Answer (score 0):

interact with the bloc using a streambuilder in your ui.  the ui creates events which the bloc code handles and response with state output

```
abstract class LoginEvent extends Equatable{
  const LoginEvent();
  @override 
  List<Object>get props=>[];
}

class LoginUser{
  final String email;
  final String password;
  const LoginUser(this.email,this.password);
  String get getEmail { return this.email;}
  String get getPassword{ return this.password;}
}
class AuthenticateEvent extends LoginEvent{
  final LoginUser user;
  const AuthenticateEvent(this.user);
  @override 
  List<Object> get props => [user];
  LoginUser get getUser{return this.user;}
}


class LoginState extends Equatable{
 final LoginView _login;
 const LoginState(this._login);
 @override 
 List<Object> get props => [_login];
 LoginView get getLogin {return this._login;}
}

class BlocLogin
{
  Stream<LoginState> get loginStream => _loginController.stream;
  final _loginController = BehaviorSubject<LoginState>();

  void dispose()
  {
    _loginController.close();
  }
  authenticate(BuildContext context,LoginEvent loginEvent) async
  {

    if (loginEvent is AuthenticateEvent)
    {
        LoginView param =
          new LoginView(loginEvent.getUser.getEmail, loginEvent.getUser.getPassword);
          
          LoginView loginValue =await Provider.of<Api>(context, listen: false)
          .addLogin(context, param);

            if (loginValue.returnMessage == "Failed") {
              DialogCaller.showIncorrectLoginDialog(context).then((value2) {});
            } else {
                Provider.of<Api>(context, listen: false).dataCache.login = loginValue;
                LoginState loginState=new LoginState(loginValue);
                _loginController.sink.add(loginState);
            }
    }

  }


}
```